# how to use Pos machine N8110?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, point-of-sale

I have this project in which I have to develop an application that would also use POS.

I developed the web service in ASP.NET and now I got the POS machine from Client, He previously said that there would be a SDK with the machine, But now We didn't get it with the macine, However I downloaded some code sample by googling for it.

I wasn't able to connect GPRS in the macine, then somehow I fixed it and now POS screen is showing GPRS signals.

But I cannot connect POS to my application, somebody please help me, I would appreciate if you give me a detailed workflow of using POS machines including server and client end configuration with steps.

Thanks in Advance,
Ramzy Virani.

Comment: Check... they must have some API and its documentation

Comment: there is not... that's why I am asking here, they are not willing to help either.

Comment: Only option... return back their dumb POS and purchase another one that has development support. :)

Comment: I googled and found this one is chinese one, most listings come from alibaba.com

Comment: Could you please help me understanding POS machines including Server and Client end Configuration step by step?

Comment: I want to write code for this machine. Would you please give some suggestion where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. POS machine which was given by client was not good, He ordered this machine from online ecommerce website, I suggested the client to get new machine from a local vendor, New machine was good and my code just ran on it like a charm.